# SQL update from values reference

Tags: sql, postgresql

Need to multiple update jsonb field using "||".
Is any solution to make a reference inside update from values query ?

```
update permission as p set
    "access" = pu.access
from (values
    (1, 'tags', p.access || '{"read": false, "create": false, "delete": false, "update": false}'::jsonb),
    (1, 'categories', p.access || '{"delete": false, "update": false}'::jsonb)
) as pu(roleId, sectionName, access)
where p."roleId" = pu.roleId and p."sectionId" = (select id from permission_section where sectionName = pu.sectionName);
```

Wrong part is:

```
p.access || '{"read": false, "create": false, "delete": false, "update": false}'::jsonb)
```

an error here:

```
[42P01] ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "p" 
There is an entry for table "p", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the  of the query.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the concatenation to the SET part, instead of the VALUES. Something like this:

```
UPDATE permission AS P 
SET "access" = p.access || pu.access -- concat over here
FROM
    ( VALUES ( 1, 'tags', '{"read": false, "create": false, "delete": false, "update": false}' :: jsonb )
    , ( 1, 'categories', '{"delete": false, "update": false}' :: jsonb ) 
    ) AS pu ( roleId, sectionName, access ) 
WHERE
    P."roleId" = pu.roleId 
AND P."sectionId" = ( SELECT ID FROM permission_section WHERE sectionName = pu.sectionName );
```